# How to install 5.2 version of PHP in wamp

Tags: php, wamp

I have wampserver 2.5 installed on my machine which has PHP 5.5.12

But I need to setup and application which is built in PHP 5.2. So how do I use this 5.2 version of PHP?

Comment: download and install new PHP

Comment: Why do you need an old, unsupported version of PHP? Can't you upgrade (even if only to 5.3)?

Comment: left click wamp > php > version > get more > install exe --- Does this work?

Comment: SIMPLY DON'T DO IT. PHP 5.2 is outdated since 2009, there's absolutly no reason to use it. I know, some companies still use 5.2 for their projects, but do you really want to work with them ? Nobody should support this in any kind of way.

Comment: I know this is not suggested but this is an old application developed in PHP 5.2 and client want some changes into it but don't want move over to 5.2 as it will take time.

Comment: @Panique 000webhost offers only php 5.2 for free hosting.

Comment: @AlexCoroza Then don't use it. It's unbelievable that people still do such things, even 5 years after 5.2 is dead.

Comment: @Panique I just decided to find a new free webhost hahah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get that far back in history, you may find it easier to install one of the old WampServer 2.2 releases.

You can find the old releases [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/)

Comment: in description you have: "PHP: 5.3.4 or 5.4.3"

Comment: Wait. does it mean I have to uninstall my current wamp2.5 to install an earlier version of wamp? I need to toggle php5.5 and php5.4 since i have projects built with mysql syntax, and pdo/mysqli/etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a special extension to WampServer 2, which will let you install PHP 5.2.11 in your WampServer.

Here's the download link: [WampServer Extension for PHP 5.2.11](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/PHP/WampServer2-PHP5211.exe/download?use_mirror=softlayer-ams&download=)

Answer (score 0):

WampServer Extension for PHP 5.2.11 - is not the best solution, as you could get compatibility error [error image](http://puu.sh/iLHkf/fdfc7b7c68.png).
Better to use RiggsFolly solution and install older wamp version.

Comment: what is RiggsFolly solution

Comment: @user1531437
He mean above answer... RiggsFolly is a user.